# Was able to push logs but failed while calling WLClient.connect()

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

I am working on IBM MobileFirst client being android native app.

I have a weird issue I am writing the following code to initialize WLClient.

```
WLClient client = WLClient.createInstance(context); 
 client.connect(new WLResponseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(WLResponse wlResponse) {
                Log.d("Success--- MFP_connect",wlResponse.getResponseText());

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(WLFailResponse wlFailResponse) {
Log.d("fail-- MFP_connect",wlFailResponse.getErrorMsg());
            }
        });
```

In My android Monitor I see a log saying

```
fail-- MFP_connect: The service is currently not available.
```

But when I am trying to push logs or analytics to the server. They are reaching the server successfully.

I am connecting to http enterprise server.

What could be the issue.

Comment: Can you collect a packet trace and share it?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Chevy... I uninstalled the app and installed it back and it worked... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@rocky solved his issue by uninstalling the app and reinstalling. The device may have been caching the previous response.